# How to prevent an app included in cached background process from being killed by the system?

Tags: android, processing

Im using an android device. When I open : settings » apps » running, the app which I want to run 24×7 is included in the cached background process, due to which the system kills this app.
Can it be prevented?
Is it possible to make an app run 24×7 which is included in the cached background processes?

I hope I conveyed the question... Please answer it briefly bcoz I'm a beginner...

Answer (score 2):

If your "background process" lends itself to a `Service`, you may want to consider implementing a foreground service. Click [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) for more info on foreground services. According to the docs:

> A foreground service is a service that's considered to be something
>   the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for the system
>   to kill when low on memory.

This is one (relatively common) way to prevent the OS from automatically killing your app. However, you do need to create a notification for the user that lets them know your service is a foreground service. You could also opt to set the priority to `MIN` if you don't necessary want the user to always see your notification in the status bar.